# javaScript field validations using in php file

Tags: php, javascript

i'm working on php form which needs the field validations using JavaScript
but i don't know how to use that in php as i'm a new guy to this one. some how i tried to do it by the following code

```
<?php

 session_start();
 // include_once('header.php');

?>

<div id="contentarea">

<div style="background-color:#3fa0c1;color:#FFF">
 <h2 style="color:#FFF"> Checkout </h2>
</div>
<br/>  
<h4> Welcome to Checkout. <br/>
Please fill in the fields below to complete your purchase! 
</h4><br/>


<form action=" " method="POST" name="Form" onsubmit="return ValidateForm();"  style="color:#000000; font-size:18px;" 

<?php switch ($_GET["checkoutType"]) {
        case "Guest":   echo 'action="guestCheckout.php"'; break;
        case "Register": echo 'action="registerCheckout.php"'; break;
    }
?>

>   
    <h3> BILLING ADDRESS </h3><br/>

    First Name*
    <input style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;" name="firstname" size="40" id="firstname"/> <br/>

    Last Name* 
    <input style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="lastname" size="40"/><br/>

    Email Address* 
    <input style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="email" size="40"/><br/>

    Confirm Email Address* 
    <input style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="email2" size="40"/><br/>

    Telephone* 
    <input style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="telephone" size="40"/><br/>

    Address* <br/>
    <input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="addr1" id="addr1" size="40"/><br/>
    <input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="addr2" id="addr2" size="40"/><br/>

    Country*  <br/>
    <!-- input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="country" size="40"/><br/-->
    <select name="country" id="country">
         <option value="select_country"> Select Country </option>
         <option value="US"> United States </option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    City*  <br/>
    <input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="city" size="40"/><br/>

    Zip Code* 
    <input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;" name="postcode" size="40"/><br/>

    State* <br/>
    <!-- input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="state" size="40"/><br/-->
    <select name="region" id="state">
         <option value="select_state"> Select Region</option>
         <option value="FL"> Florida </option>
         <option value="GA"> Georgia </option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    Company
    <input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;" name="company" size="40"/><br/>

    <input name="ship_to_same_addr" type="checkbox"  checked="checked" /> Ship to the same address. <br/><br/>

<h3> SHIPPING METHOD </h3><br/>

    <b> Post Office: Priority Mail (USA) - First Class (International) </b> <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method" checked="checked" />  Fixed <b> $6.95</b>. <br/><br/>

<h3> PAYMENT METHOD </h3><br/>

    <input type="radio" name="pay_method" id="pay_method" checked="checked" />  Credit Card (Authorize.net) <br/><br/>

    Credit Card Type*
    <!--input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="cc_type" size="40"/><br/ -->
    <select name="cc_type" id="cc_type">
     <option value="AE"> American Express </option>
     <option value="DI"> Discover </option>
     <option value="MC"> Master Card </option>
     <option value="VI"> Visa </option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    Credit Card Number*
    <input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="cc_number" id="cc_number" size="40"/><br/>

    Credit Card Security Code*
    <input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="cc_cid" id="cc_cid" size="40"/><br/>

    Expiration Date*<br/>
    <!-- input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="cc_exp_month" size="20"/-->
     <select name="cc_exp_month" id="cc_exp_month">
         <option value="select_month"> Select Month </option>
         <option value="01"> 01 - January </option>
         <option value="02"> 02 - February </option>
         <option value="03"> 03 - March </option>
         <option value="04"> 04 - April </option>
         <option value="05"> 05 - May </option>
         <option value="06"> 06 - June </option>
         <option value="07"> 07 - July  </option>
         <option value="08"> 08 - August </option>
         <option value="09"> 09 - September </option>
         <option value="10"> 10 - October </option>
         <option value="11"> 11 - November </option>
         <option value="12"> 12 - December </option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <!-- input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="cc_exp_year" size="20"/--><br/>
    <select name="cc_exp_year" id="cc_exp_year">
         <option value="select_year"> Select Year </option>
         <option value="2012"> 2012 </option>
         <option value="2013"> 2013 </option>
         <option value="2014"> 2014 </option>
         <option value="2015"> 2015 </option>
         <option value="2016"> 2016 </option>
         <option value="2017"> 2017 </option>
         <option value="2018"> 2018 </option>
         <option value="2019"> 2019 </option>
         <option value="2020"> 2020 </option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    Coupon Code
     <input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="coupon_code" size="40"/><br/>

    Comments
    <textarea rows="6" cols="40" name="comments"></textarea><br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Place Order Now" />

</form>


<script>
function ValidateForm()
{
    var firstname = document.Form.firstname;
    var lastname = document.Form.lastname;

    var email = document.Form.email;
    var email2 = document.Form.email2;   
    var telephone = document.Form.telephone;

    var address = document.Form.addrl;
    var address = document.Form.addr2;
     var country = document.Form.country;
     var city = document.Form.city;

     var postcode = document.Form.postcode;
     var state = document.Form.state;
     var company = document.Form.company;
     var creditcardtype = document.Form.cc_type;
     var creditcardnumber = document.Form.cc_number;
     var creditcardsecuritycode = document.Form.cc_cid;
     var expirationdate = document.Form.cc_exp_month;
     var expirationdate = document.Form.cc_exp_month;


    if (firstname.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter your last name.");
        firstname.focus();
        return false;
    }  


    if (lastname.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter your last name.");
        lastname.focus();
        return false;
    }  

    if (email.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter e-mail address.");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0)
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (email2.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter confirm e-mail address.");
        email2.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (email2.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0)
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
        email2.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(email.value != email2.value)
    {
      window.alert("Please enter email & confirm email both same");
      return false;
    }

    if  (telephone.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter your telephone number.");
        telephone.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (addr1.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter your address1.");
        add1.focus();
        return false;
    }
     if (addr2.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter your address2.");
        add2.focus();
        return false;
    }

   if (country.selectedIndex < 1)
    {
        alert("Please select country.");
        country.focus();
        return false;
    }
     if (city.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter city.");
        city.focus();
        return false;
    }
     if (postcode.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter zip code.");
        postcode.focus();
        return false;
    }
     if (state.selectedIndex < 1)
    {
        window.alert("Please enter state.");
        state.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (cc_type.selectedIndex < 1)
    {
        window.alert("Please enter credit card type.");
        cc_type.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (cc_number.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter credit card number.");
        cc_number.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (cc_cid.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter credit card security code.");
        cc_cid.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (cc_exp_month.selecedIndex < 1)
    {
        window.alert("Please enter expiry date.");
        cc_exp_montht.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (cc_exp_year.selectedIndex < 1)
    {
        window.alert("Please enter expiry date.");
        cc_exp_year.focus();
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}


</script>

</div>
<?php 

//include_once('footer.php')

?>
```

it seems working fine but what i need to do is to show the error message after each field validation is done instead of showing the alert boxes...how can i do that
any help will be appreciated.....thanks in advance.

Comment: Painful design... 10 fields unfilled, you end up with 10 alerts. You should 'gang up' the individual error messages into a single one. "please fix the following errors...".

Comment: dear Marc B can u please show me how can i do that....

Comment: @MarcB - 10 unfilled fields will result in ONE alert, an alert for the first unfilled field. Much easier to understand than a "ganged up" intimidating list of things you did not do.

Comment: @mplungjan. no. 10 alerts. get one alert, fix field, get another alert, fix another field, blah blah blah. horribly user unfriendly

Comment: So fill in the fields. What is needed is a clear indication of which fields are mandatory. The above is a little old fashioned but will work and not surprise anyone who ever filled in a form. The way you said it, it sounded like you would get 10 alerts one after the other. In your case you will get the same. 1 BIG alert, fill in a field, one LESS big alert, fill in one field.

Comment: thanks for ur responses.....i don't want to get any alert boxes here, after the validation of each field...just it need to display an error message after each field...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to effectively manage the form validations.
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try javascript validation
You can `add div or span with display property none`. and then `if error then in that span/div display block and show error in that div/span`. Please see code below  for example.

In HTML

```
 <input  style="height:20px; margin-bottom:10px;"  name="name" size="40"/><br/>
<span id="name_error" style="display:none"></span>
```

In javascript

```
<script>
function ValidateForm()
{
   var name = document.Form.name;

  if(name.value == ''){
    document.getElementById('name_error').innerHTML = 'Please provide name!';
    document.getElementById('name_error').style.display = 'block';        
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }else{
    document.getElementById('name_error').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('name_error').style.display = 'none';        
  }
 }
</script>
```

please try this, I hope it will be work for you, Here if error exist for that field then display error in that span else again display none.

Thaks.

Comment: Would be simpler to just drop in the jQuery validation in my opinion

Comment: @Er.Anurag jain i tried with the above given code..but of use....it's not displaying anything....

Comment: @abc123 : Yes there was an error in javascript code which i have done correct..in place of `if(name  == '')` We have to use `if(name.value == '')`....